# Application Insights Live Metrics Stream of Azure Function periodically switches between "No servers online" and "3 servers online"

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-functions-runtime

I've created an HTTP-triggered Azure Function (V1) on Consumption Plan.
When i watch the live metrics stream, the display constantly switches between "No servers online" and "3 servers online" in an interval of ~5 seconds.
This happens under load and also when not a single request is hitting the function.
I'm wondering if this is a display problem in application insights or if there is something wrong with my function app.
Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: Funny, I experienced the same problem using a Azure Service Fabric solution so I suspect it has to do with the Application Insights Live Metrics Stream, not with the function app.

Comment: Please share your app name with us privately along with a timeframe so we can investigate. Instructions [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately).

Comment: I just tried this on my own app, and I see my Live Stream flipping every few seconds between "No servers" and "1 servers online". So it does appear to be an AI Live Stream issue. The only thing I want to confirm is that after a while of no activity, your "3 servers online" should go to "No servers online" once the unused instances spin down.

Comment: I'm getting the same today

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue. We're looking into it.

Comment: @mathewc that's correct. it looks like Azure Function autoscaling is behaving correctly but the livestream has got issues.